# Combine data from 2 AJAX calls into one array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

The array should be used as Autocomplete suggestions for this searchbox:

```
<input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Type here...">
```

I tried to combine AJAX calls but I'm getting these errors:

`Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined`

`Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

If you have an idea of how to properly structure this, please let me know.

Comment: are both ajax call on same condition if so they can be handled at php end

Comment: Are you looking for them to go in order? Ajax 1 fires, then once it's done, ajax 2 fires?

Comment: So one hits your local server and one hits a remote api? Correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started moving in the right direction – you need an array that both AJAX calls can access, but you are modifying the array wrong – you need to add new elements, not re-assign the whole array, eg:

```
$.map(list, function(v,i) {
    results.push({
        label: v.Title + ' (' + v.Year + ')',
        value: v.Title
    });
});
```

Another mistake is initialising autocomplete plug-in before you get the data – it would make more sense to prepare the array first, and then initialise autocomplete when all async tasks (your AJAX calls are async tasks) are done. See this example: [multiple ajax calls wait for last one to load, then execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465177/multiple-ajax-calls-wait-for-last-one-to-load-then-execute)

Comment: You shouldn't use 'response' any longer, it became simpler: $(".searchbox").autocomplete({source: results});

Comment: If you check the url's there is request.term and it is not mentioned anywhere in the code - you need to either replace it with some correct word or with existing variable. replace var results; in the top with var results = []; so the array gets initialised - this should help!