# Set variable after if in Pre-request-Script in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I searched the community and found questions the are a little bit like mine but i could not find a answer to my question. I think for someone who knows javascript and Postman its easy. So i hope you can help me!

I have two GET Statements which asks a server and set the answer number as variable in my Postman Environment that works fine.

```js
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("state_server1", jsonData.results[0].attrs.state);
```

and the same for my other Server. 
Now i have a PUT Statement which uploads the variable from state-server1 and state-server2 in a CMS that works fine. 
Now i want to have a if query which checks if the variables state_server 1 === 0 && state_server 2 === 0 are both 0 and create a new variable state_server 12 = No problems!

So the code would be simply in my head likely so:

```
var state_server 1
var state_server 2
if(state_server 1 === 0 && state_server 2 === 0){
make new variable state_server12 = problems!
```

Hope you understand me and you can help me!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465177/multiple-ajax-calls-wait-for-last-one-to-load-then-execute

Comment: then what's error in your code?

Comment: I dont have a error, i just dont know how to set the "new" variable after the if query.

Comment: create a global variable, `var state_server12 = null` and then assign value after `get()` requests.

Comment: Do u mean that way? 
var state_server12 = null;
var state_server1;
var state_server2;

if (state_server1 === 0 && var state_server2 === 0){
    state_server45.get("everything is fine");
}

Comment: no. `var state_server12 = null; if(state_server 1 === 0 && state_server 2 === 0){ state_server12 ='problems'; }`

Comment: With that i'll get this Error: There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  ReferenceError: state_server1 is not defined 
Does this "script" find the variable state_server1 in the if query? I set it as Environment variable :/

Comment: add a jsfiddle to debug your code

Comment: I am sorry i dont know what you mean. I am a beginner. In Postman & Javascript